# Python: How to convert a number which ll separated by comma as number count increases?

Tags: python, number-systems

I have a number like: 100  I am showing here as it. 
But when I am trying to show a number as 1000 then want to display as 1,000.& so on like 1,00,000 likewise.

**Below structure**

Number         Formatted As

10                  10

100                 100

1000                1,000

10000               10,000

100000              1,00,000

1000000             10,00,000

10000000            1,00,00,000

100000000           10,00,00,000

1000000000          1,00,00,00,000

10000000000         10,00,00,00,000

All the above things I want to do in python.

I thought of using regex but couldn't get an way how to proceed.

Any one having any idea?

Comment: @DonkeyKong: It is not exactly thousand separators.

Comment: So you want the rightmost comma separated digit group to have the width 3 and all others to be two digits wide?

Comment: @AKS Oops, nice catch. I just assumed, I've never seen numbers separated as provided.

Comment: @ByteCommander, looks like the rightmost should be width 3, all else 2.

Comment: @AKS It *is* a duplicate. You need to set the `locale` to `en_IN`.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Oh, yeah. That's what I meant... Confused left and right, duh >.< It's still too early in the morning.

Comment: @BhargavRao I never said it wasn't. Just that it is not _thousand separators_. `en_IN` it is indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recognize this way of separating numbers as the one used in India.  So I think you can get what you want using `locale`:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'hi_IN')
locale.format("%d", 10000000000, grouping=True)
```

The exact locale to use may be different on your system; try `locale -a | grep IN` to get a list of Indian locales you have installed.

Comment: I tried with using as: **locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')**. Worked fine for me.

Comment: @danny: Yeah, that's using the default locale on your machine, which may be fine since you're probably doing this to match your own regional settings.  People running your code on systems configured for other countries would need an explicit locale name if they want the to print in "lakh" style.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated:** This code now supports both `int` and `float` numbers!

You could write a little number-to-string converting function yourself, like this one:

```
def special_format(n):
    s, *d = str(n).partition(".")
    r = ",".join([s[x-2:x] for x in range(-3, -len(s), -2)][::-1] + [s[-3:]])
    return "".join([r] + d)
```

It's simple to use:

```
print(special_format(1))
print(special_format(12))
print(special_format(123))
print(special_format(1234))
print(special_format(12345))
print(special_format(123456))
print(special_format(12345678901234567890))
print(special_format(1.0))
print(special_format(12.34))
print(special_format(1234567890.1234567890))
```

The above example would result in this output:

```
1
12
123
1,234
12,345
1,23,456
1,23,45,67,89,01,23,45,67,890
1.0
12.34
1,23,45,67,890.1234567
```

[See this code running on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6LZWrP)

Comment: Updated my code snippet to also support float decimal numbers.